# Adding only odd or even numbers.

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a function that when given an array of numbers and a condition, such as odd or even, the numbers which match that 
condition are added together. If no values matches the condition, 0 should be returned.

How can I do this without Array.prototype.filter() -- my textbook tells me to do it without this method.

What if statements should I use?

```
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "even"));        => 6
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "odd"));         => 9
console.log(conditionalSum([13, 88, 12, 44, 99], "even"));   => 144
console.log(conditionalSum([], "odd"));                      => 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far??

Comment: I agree with @iNullPointer, and check out the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

Comment: `filter` wouldn't be the best tool for this anyway, because it creates an unnecessary intermediate array

Comment: `const conditionalSum=(_,$)=>_.reduce((o,_)=>o+($=='even'&&!(_%-~!+[])||$=='odd'&&_%-~!+[]?_:+[]),+[]);`

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array by choosing the right callback for reducing.

```js
function conditionalSum(array, parts) {
    return array.reduce(
        parts === 'even' 
            ? (s, v) => s + (!(v % 2) && v)
            : (s, v) => s + (v % 2 && v),
        0
   );
}

console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "even"));      //   6
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "odd"));       //   9
console.log(conditionalSum([13, 88, 12, 44, 99], "even")); // 144
console.log(conditionalSum([], "odd"));                    //   0
```

Comment: Actually, this one is much faster, as it will not check the condition for each entry and prepare the appropriate callback at the beginning. there is nor reason to dv this (whoever did without any explanation/comment) ans, as this make sense irrespective of the question make sense or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
function conditionalSum(arr, cond) {
  var total_length = arr.length;
  var total_num = 0;
  if (total_length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (cond === 'even') {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
        total_num += arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  if (cond == 'odd') {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
        total_num += arr[i];
      }
    }
  }

  return total_num;
}
```

check this out

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Neat Solution To Your Problem

```js
function conditionalSum(nums, operation) {
  var condition = ['even', 'odd'];
  sum = 0;
  nums.forEach(function(i) {
    if (condition[i % 2] == operation) {
      sum += i;
    }
  });
  return sum;
}

console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "even"));
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "odd"));
console.log(conditionalSum([13, 88, 12, 44, 99], "even"));
console.log(conditionalSum([], "odd"));
```

Hope, this will be helpful.

Comment: really? you included jQuery?

Comment: exactly my point 57 minutes ago when jQuery was included in the snippet @KoushikChatterjee

Comment: Oh that was included by mistake. I didn't noticed that. And I don't think its a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing a conditional function as a parameter.

This way you can reuse the same function for a lot of different operations.

```js
/**
 * conditionalSum
 * Runs a list of numbers against a custom conditional function and accumulators the values that passes
 * @param {number[]} list
 * @param {(n: number) => boolean} condition
 * @returns {number}
 */
function conditionalSum(list, condition) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        var value = list[index];
        if (condition(value)) {
            total += value;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
//TEST
function isEven(n) { return n % 2 === 0; }
function isOdd(n) { return n % 2 !== 0; }
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], isEven));
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], isOdd));
console.log(conditionalSum([13, 88, 12, 44, 99], isEven));
console.log(conditionalSum([], isOdd));
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
    const conditionalSum = (numbers, operation) => {
      const value = operation === "even" ? 0 : 1;
      return numbers.filter(number => number % 2 === value).reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);
    }
    
    console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "even"));      //   6
    console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "odd"));       //   9
    console.log(conditionalSum([13, 88, 12, 44, 99], "even")); // 144
    console.log(conditionalSum([], "odd"));                    //   0
```

Answer (score -2):

There are actually several options for solving the issue.

The first one is using `filter` to get the list of expected numbers then sum them up 
 with `reduce`. This is for achieving best readability.

```js
let conditionalSum = (arr, parity) => {
  return arr
      .filter(num => parity === 'even' ? num % 2 === 0 : num % 2 !== 0)
      .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
};
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "even"));
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "odd"));
console.log(conditionalSum([13, 88, 12, 44, 99], "even"));
console.log(conditionalSum([], "odd"));
```

Using `for` loop meanwhile helps provide a more performant solution.

```js
let conditionalSum = (arr, parity) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let num of arr) {
    if(parity === 'even' && num % 2 !== 0
    || parity === 'odd' && num % 2 === 0) {
      continue;
    }
    sum += num;
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "even"));
console.log(conditionalSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "odd"));
console.log(conditionalSum([13, 88, 12, 44, 99], "even"));
console.log(conditionalSum([], "odd"));
```

So it's really up to your use case for picking the proper solution. I think you should go with readability ones most of the time.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use `.filter()` though. And using only `.reduce()` (without filtering first) is pretty readable and avoids an unnecessary iteration.

Comment: @H77 Yes I know. But I still think using `reduce` together with `filter` is more readable. Anyway, what I want the OP to understand is that he/she shouldn't care about that most of the time. Readability is way more important than the tiny performance improvement.

Comment: Using only `reduce` isn't that complicated to understand though. Also the performance improvement wouldn't be tiny if the arrays were large. Actually to me using only `reduce` would be clearer as it can be made obvious that only odd/even numbers are included. Btw wasn't me who downvoted!

Comment: @H77 filter itself quickly notices readers about the conditions. About performance, I have already mentioned about only applying that solution in appropriate use cases. But in my experience,  we won’t have large arrays most of the time. Also hope that SO can show downvoters so I can ask them for reasons to improve my answer.